# How do I create a card view in HTML from the form data that I have made in django?

Tags: python, html, django, crm

I am creating a Django CRM where I am using the forms to acquire data about any company. What I want to do is when I or anybody has written about the details of any companies and submitted them - they are going to be saved as card views in companies.html.

Can anybody help me regarding this?

companies.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4 mt-4">
    <a href="{% url 'company-create' %}" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-sm text-white-50"></i> Create Company</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <a class="small" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Back</a>
    </div>


</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

company-create.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %} 

{% block content %}
```

```
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4 mt-4">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Company Create</h1>
    </div>          

    <!-- Main Content Here -->
    <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
      <div class="card-body p-0">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="p-5">
              <div class="text-center">
                <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Create a Company!</h1>
              </div>
              <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{user_form | crispy}}
                {{profile_form | crispy}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Update</button>
              </form>
              <hr>
              <div class="text-center">
                <a class="small" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Back</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
{% endblock content %}
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from apps.userprofile.models import Profile

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional')
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional')
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Enter a valid email address')

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password1',
        'password2',
    ]


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
    ]


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = [
        'bio',
        'phone_number',
        'birth_date',
        'profile_image'
    ]


class CompanyForm(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(label="Enter Company Name",max_length= 50)
email = forms.EmailField(label="Enter Email")
phone_number = forms.CharField(label="Enter Phone Number",max_length=12)
contact_name = forms.CharField(label="Enter Contact Persons Name",max_length=50)
file = forms.FileField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
        'username'
        'profile_image',
    ]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView

from .forms import SignUpForm, UserForm, ProfileForm, CompanyForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from apps.userprofile.models import Profile

class HomeView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'common/home.html'

class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
template_name = 'common/dashboard.html'
login_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    print(self.request.user.id)
    context['book_list'] = self.request.user
    return context

class SignUpView(CreateView):
form_class =  SignUpForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
template_name = 'common/register.html'

class MessageView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'common/messages.html'

class CompanyView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'common/companies/companies.html'

class CompanyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
user_form = CompanyForm
template_name = 'common/companies/company-create.html'

def post(self, request):

    post_data = request.POST or None
    file_data = request.FILES or None

    user_form = CompanyForm(post_data)

    if user_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your company was successfully created!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('comapanies'))

    context = self.get_context_data(
                                    user_form=user_form
                                )

    return self.render_to_response(context)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserForm, ProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from apps.userprofile.models import Profile


class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
template_name = 'common/profile.html'

class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
user_form = UserForm
profile_form = ProfileForm
template_name = 'common/profile-update.html'

def post(self, request):

    post_data = request.POST or None
    file_data = request.FILES or None

    user_form = UserForm(post_data, instance=request.user)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(post_data, file_data, instance=request.user.profile)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        profile_form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your profile was successfully updated!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('profile'))

    context = self.get_context_data(
                                    user_form=user_form,
                                    profile_form=profile_form
                                )

    return self.render_to_response(context)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Along with the codes I am also attaching some screenshots of the CRM:

Dashboard:
Like the cards called companies and contacts I want the company details to be shown in cards -
[image]

Companies:
Here after clicking on the create contact button we are redirected to the company create form.
[image]

Create-Company:
Now here after the update button is clicked with the filled out form details I want to redirect the form to the contacts page with the newly added company details shown below the create company button in a card form.
[image]

Comment: So, it is simple for me if you use the `def` as function rather than `class` as function. Where, inside it you can call the model within it use as a variable, put in the function dictionary and retrieve within the `companies.html` using a loop from this parameter.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are proceeding with it??

Comment: I've added the example below using normal function as view not class. try this approach and see if it can help you. If yes, may you add it as the answer and add up for the answer? I hope it helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach as you requested an example using plain function as view not class. You will need to do some settings in settings.py such as install Pillow (if you are not done it already). See if it can help you.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class CompanyDetail(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(label="Enter Company Name",max_length= 50)
email = models.EmailField(label="Enter Email")
phone_number = models.CharField(label="Enter Phone Number",max_length=12)
contact_name = models.CharField(label="Enter Contact Persons Name",max_length=50)

image = models.ImageField(upload_to='tour_images', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,
from .models import CompanyDetail


def show_company_cards(request):

    company_details = CompanyDetail.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'company.html', {'company_details': company_details})
```

company.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4 mt-4">
    <a href="{% url 'company-create' %}" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-sm text-white-50"></i> Create Company</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <a class="small" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Back</a>
    </div>
<!-- this is the place of the closing container fluid that is in the bottom -->

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    {% for detail in company_details %}

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="contact-box center-version">


                    <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="{{ detail.image.url}}">

                    <h3 class="m-b-xs"><strong>{{detail.name}}</strong></h3>

                    <div class="font-bold">{{detail.contact_name}}</div>

                    <address class="m-t-md">

                        <strong>{{detail.email}}</strong><br>

                        <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> {{detail.phone_number}}

                    </address>

            </div>
        </div>

{% endfor %}


     </div>
  </div>

<!-- container fluid closer (test to see if it works) if no remove an put it back-->

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```